# Selenium download button indicates a zip file download by browser in Java

Tags: java, file, selenium, download, selenide

I have a download button without href link in a webpage.
I find it with findExtendedelement and click on it.
After the click a zip file download on the hard drive (i dont know where, and it shouldn't be matter)
I would like to catch this downloaded zip and put it in my project, for example build/reports/tests/temp folder.

Is it possible with selenium?

Update

The HTML looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnhlH.jpg

I tried this code:

```
@Test
public void userCanDownloadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
 // Folder to store downloads and screenshots to.
 reportsFolder = "./src/test/profiles/chrome/downloads/";

 open("http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.16/");

 // Download files
 $("a[href='/2.16/chromedriver_win32.zip']").download();
    $(By.xpath(".//a[@href='/2.16/chromedriver_mac32.zip']")).download();

    // Count files in folder, assert 2
    int downloadsCount = new File(reportsFolder+"2.16").listFiles().length;
    assertEquals("Should be 2 files but founded " + downloadsCount,  
          downloadsCount, 2); 

    // Clean after test
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(reportsFolder+"2.16"));
}
```

Result:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The element does not have href attribute:

The code is from: 
http://selenide-recipes.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-download-file-with-selenide.html

I'm looking for something like that, I can handle the downloaded file in my project. (in reportsFolder path)
Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work, because the ExtendedElement (findExtendedElement("span", "class", "download_0") doesn't have an "a href" tag)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this xpath: `"//span[contains(@class,'download_o')]"` should work

Comment: Same result:(
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The element does not have href attribute: <span class="download_0"></span>